# Raw keyboard capture with process.stdin doesn't work as expected?

Tags: node.js, stdin

**I'm having problems capturing Raw keyboard input in a terminal** on windows. This is driving me crazy, because I know that I had implemented this with older versions of nodejs (a year + ago)

Using the latest versions of **NodeJS** (currently using **4.2.2**), capturing input **seems buggy**.. Unless I am missing something?

**What I am running:**

```
stdin = process.stdin;
stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    if (data == '\u0003') { process.exit(); }
    process.stdout.write('Captured Key : ' + data + "\n");
});
stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
stdin.setRawMode(true);
stdin.resume();
```

**What I am expecting:**

Immediately after running, the program should react to whatever key is pressed, and output:

```
Captured Key : T
Captured Key : E
Captured Key : S
. . . etc
```

**What I am getting:**

After running the program, the first keyboard input, acts as if it is **NOT** captured in Raw and it is captured and displayed on screen.

Then when I press the **ENTER** key, the text I just typed gets pushed to the handler function, **AND THEN** the program will accept further input in **raw** as expected.

Looks like as if the program requires an ENTER keystroke to initiate a proper raw mode input mode?

[image]

***pic related***: I typed TEST (ENTER). Then the program works as expected.

Anyone knows what is this all about? I can't find anything. Also I don't want to use any external libraries. Thanks!

Comment: I would love an answer to this as well.  I am experiencing the exact same behavior in node v0.10.46 on Windows Server 2012 R2.